# Appropriate response to Process.Start(URL); failure?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-interface, user-experience

I have a .NET 4 application that uses Process.Start(URL); to open the user's default browser and take them to my update page if they accept an update request. This works fine for most people, but I'm getting crash logs from some users where this fails with:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have chastised myself for ignoring the possibility of failure here and using naive examples from the web and now I'm trying to work out what to do. My first instinct is to show a general "Couldn't open browser, here's the URL" message and maybe add a button to copy it to the clipboard, but can I do better?

- A more robust way to open the URL? Although this seems to be the standard answer to questions about opening URLs, is it really the best way?
- Something more informative to say to the user? Does failure mean a misconfiguration on the user's machine? Virus-scanner blocking access, maybe?

Comment: Haven't seen this, but it certainly *sounds* like a local configuration issue - maybe deleting a default browser...

Comment: I'm getting this error right now because of a '%' in the URL eg "http://localhost/bla/foo%1"